# Position objects based on latitude and longitude in a React-Native View without showing actual map

Tags: javascript, react-native, coordinates, latitude-longitude

I have different posts with locations (latitude and longitude) and want to show all the posts to the users based on user's current location.

When the user will come to the map screen, i want to add a marker at user's current location and then draw 3 circles of 10, 20 and 30 km radius respectively. I want to show all the posts that fall in 10km radius in the first circle and same goes for the other two circles like what's shown in the image below. I am getting the data from the API and the radius grouping is already done.

[image]